# Extra script added to Phonegap app slowing performance nativeFetchMessages()

Tags: iphone, html, cordova, kendo-ui

Using Phonegap and Kendo Mobile UI, my application fills several different listviews dynamically from an SQL db accessed through the openDatabase() in phonegap. When I first start the app and click through several different lists the application navigates and populates the views very quickly. After flipping through the screens more than 15-20 times the entire app starts to slow down, and eventually crawls to a point where its hard to use.

Running on an iPhone4 - 5 or simulator doesnt make a difference.

Starting the app fresh I am greeted with the first list view.
Inspecting the web view and looking at the file list I can see index.html.
Under that the normal folders: Scripts, Images, Fonts ect..

Clicking on a list item drills into another listview. Once the page is changed and the new listview is populated I now notice a new folder under the index.html parent item. A folder called: "Extra Scripts"
Inside the Extra Scripts folder I find a new index.html file (with no children). Clicking on it opens its contents, 1 line:

```
cordova.require('cordova/exec').nativeFetchMessages()
```

Clicking on another item drills down further by changing the view again and populating another list view. On this third screen now, I notice there are 2 index.html files in the Extra Scripts folder.

In short: Anytime these views with lists on them are shown, a new file is attached to Extra Scripts. Once the number of these files gets over 12 or so, the device slows down. I do have other views in my application that do not contain dynamically populated list views, these pages do not cause an Extra Script to be created.

I am not sure if the issue exists with the Kendo Mobile ListViews or Phonegap 2.4 itself. I have also upgraded Phonegap to 2.9 which did not help.
I also have another application running the same version (2.4) and it does not experience any of these issues, although it does not concentrate on listviews has heavily, several listviews exist and no issue arises.

Another big difference between the two apps is that the broken one fills it's data from phonegaps WebSQL database plugin, where as the app that works pulls its data from ajax calls contacting a REST service.

Below is an example of how I create and initialize my list views

```
<div data-role="view" id="equipmentPage" data-title="My Network" data-layout="mobile-tabstrip" >
    <ul data-role="listview" class="equipmentlist" data-source="equipmentDS" data-template="equipmentListItemTemplate">
    </ul>
</div>



 <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="equipmentListItemTemplate">
   <div class="left wide liname">${name}</div>
   <div class="hiddenField" style='display: none'>${id}</div>
   <div class="right">
     <div class="hiddenField" style='display: none'>${id}</div>
     <div class="km-button badgeButton" id="badgeequipment_#=id#"></div>
     <button class="editEquipment" style="vertical-align: top" data-role="button" data-icon="compose"> </button>
   </div>
</script>


function equipmentliTemplateInit(){
  lockOverlay = true
  showLoadOverlay()
  console.log("equipmentInit")

  dbSelect("Select * from Equipment WHERE active = 1 and userId = " + ((temp.selected.friend > 0)?temp.selected.friend:temp.user.userID) + " AND siteId = " + temp.selected.site + "", function(tx, results){
    var equipment = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++)
    {
      equipment.push(results.rows.item(i))
    }
    fillEquipment(equipment)
    lockOverlay =false
    hideLoadOverlay()
  })

}

function fillEquipment(equipment)
{
  equipment.sort(function(a, b){
    var nameA = a.name.toLowerCase();
    var nameB = b.name.toLowerCase();
    if(nameA < nameB)
      return -1
      if(nameA > nameB)
        return 1
        return 0;
  })
  /*$(".equipmentlist").data('kendoMobileListView').destroy()
  $(".equipmentlist").html("");
  $(".equipmentlist").kendoMobileListView({
    dataSource: kendo.data.DataSource.create({data: equipment }),
    template: $("#equipmentListItemTemplate").html()
  });*/
  equipmentDS.data(equipment)
  setBadges()
  if(equipment.length < 1)
    $(".equipmentlist").html("<li><center>There are no equipment to display.<br>Use the + button to add one.</center></li>");
  defineListItemActions()
}
```

I tried to upload images but new users are unable to.